# Algorithm for selecting a subset of nodes (K <N) from a chain

Tags: algorithm, graph, chain

I am looking for an algorithm to select a subset of nodes from a chain. For example, with a given node set with "N" nodes in a temporal chain, I would like to select "K" nodes based on the criteria such that K < N. For example, what if I have to select a set of days {D1, D2, DK} with "K=3" days out of the set {D1, D2, D3,...DN} "N=7" days in a week such that I maximize the following cost given by:

[image]

I need to select the best "K" items from the set {D1,....,DN}. One possibility is that I can enumerate all possible choices and choose the best combination:

```
...
1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 1 0

...
```

Is there a well-known algorithm in Computer Science to solve this problem? If so, any pointer to appropriate resources/code might help.

PS: I am not sure whether this is the right forum, please comment below, I will repost it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by selecting K from N nodes. What are the rules ? How do you select the K nodes ? Is it select the first K nodes, random K nodes, K nodes with maximum edges ? Please be more specific

Comment: @Amir I have updated the question with a simple problem.

Comment: @ssk I didn't understand how you pick the K nodes.

Comment: @Amir, I edited the question once again

Comment: @ssk  Let's talk here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51917/n-k-nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the objective is linear, this problem has optimal substructure and thus is amenable to dynamic programming. For each `i` from 0 to K, for each `j` from 0 to N, determine the best way to choose `i` nodes from the first `j`. There's only one way to choose `i` = 0 nodes. The best way to choose `i` nodes from the first `j` > 0 is either the best way to choose `i` from the first `j` - 1, or item `j` preceded by the best way to choose `i` - 1 nodes from the first `j` - 1. By avoiding recomputing the optima for subproblems, the running time is polynomial.

Comment: seems to be O(NK) if recurrence is dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j-1]) and O(N+K) to get the resulting vector